# How to get Customer mobile number when click add cart button when order in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress

Woocommerce Wordpress :

Is there any way to ask customer to provide his phone number before placing an order?
what I need to do is that once a customer adds a product to cart (Before placing the order), customer should be asked to provide his details, plus that I need to notify the admin about the customer and products details

Comment: Im a bit confused what are you trying to achieve. Could you explain better what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please check now above my text am modify text.

Comment: Please give me solution for my problem,Is there any pugin or not?